# Java - Exception Handling - Regex - Matches method does not work with scanner input

Tags: java, regex, exception

Below code I am trying to accept only numeric (0-9) and "-" as input to set my account number.

If user enters invalid input, program should throw an exception if it is valid input program should go ahead with the second layer of conditioning (`isCheckDigitCorrect()` is another method with an algorithm, at this point that method is irrelevant) and if the second condition is also true my program should go ahead and set the account number else throw an exception.

Problem is that, my if statement always returns false.
I tried debugging to see if my regex pattern was correct, I found out that if I declare a string i.e `"123-123456"`, it matches the pattern returning true.

However, if I enter the same input as the declared regex pattern i.e `input accountNumber="123-123456"`  my test variable returns false.
 What could be the problem here? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance. (image for the description of my debugging)

[debugging output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5BpU.jpg)

```
private void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {   

      accountNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
      String regex = "123-123456";
      boolean test = regex.matches("^[0-9-]+$");

      if(accountNumber.matches("^[0-9-]+$")) { 
          if(isCheckDigitCorrect(accountNumber)) { this.accountNumber = accountNumber;

     } else { throw new
      BadAccountInputException(" Bad account number; check digit failed."); }


      } else { throw new
      BadAccountInputException("Account number must consists of numbers separated by -, other non-numeric characters not allowed"
      );


      }

      }
```

Comment: Why are you re-assiging a method parameter as the first operation? Why not just `String accountNumber = keyboard.nextLine()`?

Comment: Aside from whatever Java issue you are experiencing, your regex will provide a positive match for stuff like `1-2-3-4-5`, just `-`, `-34534`, `24534534-`, `-2334-`, etc.. You will probably want to switch your regex to be `^[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Hi Gwaithim, welcome to SO! When asking, remember to follow the [Minimal, Reproducible Example principal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, you don't write how you initiated the `keyboard` variable that may be one of the crucial points of your problem. You shall also remove all the irrelevant code and description from your code. A good formatting also makes miracles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that whatever your `keyboard.nextLine()` does, it probably returns not just `123-123456` (to take your example), but also other white space characters at the end or at the beginning of the string. And as your regular expression `^[0-9-]+$` doesn't allow any white space characters, the `matches()` method returns `false` under these circumstances.

In a similar way, you should also make sure that the character `-` from your code is really matching the one that you get from the `keyboard`. See the [different hyphens and dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes).

Comment: I also thought that would be a case, a friend suggested to use trim() method to get rid of the white space i.e accountNumber.trim().matches("^[0-9-]+$"); but that still didnt solve the problem.

Comment: OK, then maybe that `-` isn't always `-`? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Hyphens_and_dashes. Anyway, I would suggest you to really *debug* your code (stop it on a breakpoint and investigate the variables' contents). You should surely find the culprit then...